# Не получается пройти по ссылкам, чтобы спарсить инфу

Tags: php, парсер, curl, phpquery

Я пишу парсер на php, моя задача спарсить инфу с главной страницы и перейти по ссылкам, где http://fujifilm-artclub.ru/content/photo/ - фотографируй, оформляй и печатай и оттуда спарсить инфу. Мой скрипт главную  страницу открывает и парсит оттуда, а по ссылкам не переходит.

Пытался и с помощью библиотеки `phpQuery` и без нее.
На названия переменных не смотрите, делал по видосику, не очень замарачивался с переменными.

2 скрипта, первый без `phpQuery`, второй с `phpQuery`:

```
 <?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$url='http://fujifilm-artclub.ru';


  function curl_get($url)  
  { 
    $curl =curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    // curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    // curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FILE,$fp);
    $result=curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $result;
 }
  $html= curl_get('http://fujifilm-artclub.ru');
  $dom=str_get_html($html);
  $courses=$dom->find('.js_menuSection');
  foreach($courses as $course){
    
    $a=$course->find('a',0);
    echo $a->href;
    
    $fotolink = curl_get('http://fujifilm-artclub.ru' . $a->href);
   file_put_contents('1',$fotolink);
   break;
   }

?>






<?php
 require'phpQuery-onefile.php';


 $url="http://fujifilm-artclub.ru";
 function get_content($url)
 {
     $curl =curl_init();
     curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,false);
     // curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
     // curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FILE,$fp);
     $result=curl_exec($curl);
     curl_close($curl);
    
     return $result;
    
 }

 $url="http://fujifilm-artclub.ru";


$url="http://fujifilm-artclub.ru";
$file = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($file);
 $pq=pq($doc);
$menu=$pq->find('.js_menuSection a:first-child');
echo $menu;
// $href=$menu->attr('href')->html();
// echo $href;
   foreach($menu as $link)
    {
   $link = pq($link);
    $foto=$link->find('a eq(1)');
    $draw=$link->find('a eq(1)');
    $print=$link->attr('a:eq(2)');
    $share=$link->attr('a eq(3)');
;


  print_r($foto);  
 }

?>
```

Comment: NaClnik спасибо  за исправления неточностей.

Answer (score 0):

Раскомментируйте `curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);`
и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Ну да, логично. Чтобы переходил по ссылкам, надо включить FOLLOWLOCATION